# Is it possible to count the number of dimensions in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to know the level of an array as it is being built.

The code loops through a bunch of directories to create a massive multi-dimensional array.

As the array is being created, I want to know how deep in the array I am.

```
1    2    3    4
---------------------
Root
     A
          A2
          A3
          A4
               A4a
     B
          B2
          B3
     C
     D
     E
          E2
               E2a
          E3
```

In the example above, the root directory is in level 1. All single uppercase letters are in level 2. All uppercase letters with a number are in level 3. All uppercase letters with a number and a lowercase letter are in level 4.

As I'm building the array, is there any way for me to know which level I'm in? The array is being created with a recursive function.

This is a PHP question.

Comment: No there is no way, why don't you pass the current depth to your recursive function ?

Comment: Can you post the recursive function ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the recursive function. Thanks for all the comments and answers!

Comment: For history sake, this article helped with this problem: http://blog.froglogic.com/2007/04/recursion-depth-counting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick an easy answer is to simply add a "depth" parameter to your function and increment it when the function calls itself.

Comment: +1 Using recursion to work with the product of recursion — I like the sound of that.

Comment: -1 I don't get how this counts the dimension. In my eyes it covers only the case when the subdimension is in the first array element.

Comment: Even so, an array could contain a string on the first slot, and an array on the second.

Comment: @Colin - Quite true. I now understan the original issue. I'll stick with just the depth argument as Sarfraz's solution is equivalent to what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: I was able to implement your function with success, but was still not satisfied with the result, so I went back to the idea of adding a depth counter, which is what I was trying to do in the first place.  The only reason that this didn't work in the beginning was because I forgot to deincrement the depth counter in the recursive function.  I ultimately decided to abstract the counter to a class, and that solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This might be tangential to your question about the array, but you could kill two birds with one stone by using a recursive directory iterator.

```
$path_to_root = __DIR__;
$directories  = new ParentIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_to_root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::CURRENT_AS_SELF));
$iterator     = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directories, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $item)
{
    printf("%d %s\n", $iterator->getDepth() + 1, $item->getSubPathname());
}
```

Which would output something like:

```
1 Root
2 Root/A
3 Root/A/A2
3 Root/A/A3
3 Root/A/A4
4 Root/A/A4/A4a
2 Root/B
3 Root/B/B2
3 Root/B/B3
2 Root/C
2 Root/D
2 Root/E
3 Root/E/E2
4 Root/E/E2/E2a
3 Root/E/E3
```

As you can see `RecursiveIteratorIterator::getDepth()` is used to get the current depth of the recursive iterator, which is the reason for suggesting this approach.

---

## Alternative (if you must use an array)

Assuming your array structure looks something like:

```
$dirs = array(
    'Root' => array(
        'A' => array(
            'A2' => array(),
            'A3' => array(),
            'A4' => array(
                'A4a' => array(),
            ),
        ),
        'B' => array(
            'B2' => array(),
            'B3' => array(),
        ),
        'C' => array(),
        'D' => array(),
        'E' => array(
            'E2' => array(
                'E2a' => array(),
            ),
            'E3' => array(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then a *very similar* approach to getting the values from a recursive directory iterator (but this time with a recursive array iterator) can be used. A quick loop over the "parent" arrays can give us the "path" from the current item back to the root.

```
$recursive = new ParentIterator(new RecursiveArrayiterator($dirs));
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $item)
{
    // Build path from "parent" array keys
    for ($path = "", $i = 0; $i <= $iterator->getDepth(); $i++) {
        $path .= "/" . $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
    }
    // Output depth and "path"
    printf("%d %s\n", $iterator->getDepth() + 1, ltrim($path, "/"));
}
```

The output would be the same as the earlier one for the directory iterator.

**TL;DR** We can use recursive iterators from the [SPL iterators](http://php.net/spl.iterators) to make working with recursive/deep structures much simpler.

**TL;DR;TL;DR** SPL, heck yeah!

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
function array_depth($array) {
    $max_depth = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

            if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                $max_depth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_depth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc_dimensions(array $array) {
    $dimensions = 1;
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $subDimensions = calc_dimensions($value);
            if ($subDimensions > $max) {
                $max = $subDimensions;
            }
        }
    }

    return $dimensions+$max;
}

$array = array(
    array(
        array(
            4 => 5,
            array(
                6 => 6
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => 5
);

echo calc_dimensions($array)."\n";
```

Comment: Why are you using both `$max` and `$dimensions`. One of them would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are asking the wrong question. What is the final goal? For example there is a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class within SPL, maybe that will do for you? Building a big multidimensional array will eat loads of memory, so maybe simply iterating over all those files recursively would suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The directory structure and contents rarely changes, and when it does, we issue a new release. So I'm caching the array after it is created. Otherwise, yeah, we'd be screwed.